# How to remove background from binary image in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, background, extract

I have images like the following:

> [image]

I want to extract the background (in other words I want make a new image without the characters) so that i substract from the original image the background image resulting a new image with only the characters. 
I know how crop the letters but it's not what i need.

This is the background:

> [image: http://i.imgur.com/QJB3yxp.jpg]

This is the desired output:

> [image]

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to achieve. Can you edit the image by hand with an image editing program in the way you want your program to do it, and also post this edited image?

Comment: output=original_image - background

Comment: Invert your image (255-img) then extract all contours. Remove all contours that are too big/small

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: how about Mat charactersMat = image != background  ?